# Bootstrap popover hides line breaks

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am using the html code as follows to show the bootstrap popover

```
<a data-original-title="" data-content="Hi,
           Welcome !

           Sincerely,
             programmer
           "
   data-placement="bottom">
    content
</a>
```

And I initialized the popover as follows

```
$(this).popover({
            html:true
        });
```

All works fine but the problem is the content available in data-content not displayed with the spaces....It removes all the new lines and show it in the single line ....How can i overcome this....

Comment: As Arun mentioned, you'll need to use HTML in the data-content attribute. If you need to use attributes inside attributes, simply use single quotes.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You need to use `<br/>` for new line in html or use a `<pre>` tag

Ensure the `data-html="true"` attribute is present.

Comment: With Bootstrap 5, the required attribute is `data-bs-html="true"`.

Answer (score 46):

You can use `white-space: pre-wrap;` to preserve line breaks in formatting. There is no need to manually insert html elements.

```
.popover {
    white-space: pre-wrap;    
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant and needs more upvotes. I wasn't aware of the `pre-wrap` option.

Comment: This also preserves multiple adjacent spaces within the text. `white-space: pre-line` preserves just the line breaks.

Comment: Excellent ... This works for me

<Popover.Content style={{whiteSpace: "pre-wrap"}}>

Comment: This is by far the most elegant solution. It gave me this idea which worked for me in Bootstrap 5.1: `.popover-body {white-space: pre-wrap !important;}`.

Answer (score 38):

To add on to Arun P Johny's solution, if you find that your `<br />` tags in the `data-content` value are rendering as plain text in the popover content on the page, add the additional attribute `data-html="true"`, like so:

```
<a data-content="Hi,<br />Welcome !<br /><br />Sincerely,<br />programmer"
        data-html="true"
        data-placement="bottom">
    content
</a>
```

Be aware that using `data-html="true"` does introduce a potential vulnerability to [XSS attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29); don't use it with unsanitized user input.

Docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#popovers-options

Answer (score 11):

I managed to get this working by adding \n to my popover text where I want the lines to break and adding the following to my stylesheet:

```
.popover {
    white-space: pre-line;    
}
```

Thanks for the help, everyone!

Answer (score 3):

We managed to use the styling of white-space: pre-wrap except we found that added extra whitespace to the whole pop-over.  Instead we added this styling to the popover-content.

```
.popover-content {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add data-html="true" to your  tag then all your html tags inside the help text work fine,