# Breaking line inside Bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am using `&#013;` to break line inside bootstrap popover `data-content` attribute but it doesn't work. How is that possible?
Also is that possible to make some bold content in it?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
});
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script></script>
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" title="Header" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-content="Hello, i need &#013; to break line.">hover me</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap popover hides line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459691/bootstrap-popover-hides-line-breaks)

Comment: [Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14459734/9618184)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
});
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script></script>
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" title="Header" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-content="Hello, i need <br /> to break line.<b>BOLD HERE</b>" data-html="true">hover me</a>
</div>
```

Use `data-html="true"` and `<br/>`

Comment: yes but its a recommended way of doing it. :) @GragasIncoming

Comment: Also if it has solved your issue please mark the answer as accepted so it can help someone in future. :) @GragasIncoming

Comment: Yes, i will. Is that possible to make some bold text in the content?

Comment: Checkout my answer I have updated it. @GragasIncoming

Answer (score 0):

Use `<br />` to break lines in popover

Comment: and `data-html="true"`