# How can i break line in data-content attribute?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, line-breaks

```
echo "<a data-content='(1)$var3array[0] (2)$var3array[1] (3)$var3array[2]' rel='popover' href='#''
      data-original-title='Notes'> Notes </a>';
```

Here, the content displays `(1) GOOD (2) BAD(3) GREAT`

i want it to be

```
        (1) GOOD
        (2) BAD
        (3) GREAT
```

Comment: You can try this way: `echo "<a data-content='(1)$var3array[0] </br> (2)$var3array[1] </br> (3)$var3array[2]' rel='popover' href='#''
      data-original-title='Notes'> Notes </a>';`

Comment: would `<br>` work? and could you also post your js (jquery) code that is printing out that list? it would help people in answering your question

Comment: For what purpose you need to break line in data-content,,, it is not possible to break...data-content will not be visible to user

Comment: how and where you need to display these values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be set data-html="true"

```
echo "<a data-content='(1)$var3array[0] <br /> (2)$var3array[1]<br />  (3)$var3array[2]'
        data-html='true'
        data-placement='bottom'>
    content
</a>"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set data-html attribute to true and add 
 tag.

```
echo "<a data-content='(1)$var3array[0] <br />(2)$var3array[1] <br />(3)$var3array[2]' data-html="true" rel='popover' href='#' data-original-title='Notes'> Notes </a>';
```

[Refer this stackoeverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459691/bootstrap-popover-hides-line-breaks)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HTML `<br>` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp) to archieve it:

```
echo "<a data-content='(1)$var3array[0] <br /> (2)$var3array[1] <br /> (3)$var3array[2]' rel='popover' href='#'' data-original-title='Notes'> Notes </a>';
```